# Региональная переадресация на поддомен wordpress

Tags: wordpress

может ли кто то подсказать как реализовать переадресацию с основного домена на под домен, когда пользователь заходит с Москвы, какие плагины здесь нужны для отслеживания гео, или как заполнить htaccess? 
Буду очень рад подсказкам и помощи

Comment: Для определения локации я бы использовал например вот это https://2ip.ua/ru/api/our-api . А дальше - в зависимости от локации - php-редирект. Если пользователь вручную изменил город - можно ему это записать куда то в куку и перед редиректом проверять нет ли этой записи.

Comment: Спасибо, но их апишка платная, бесплатно только десять единиц в день

Comment: ну поищи бесплатную. Подобные сервисы, в основном все платные. В любом случае - чтоб всё нормально работало - нужно юзать какой-то сервис, где база айпишников своевременно обновляется.